# HTML5 canvas putImageData seems to mess with pixels not getting expected results

Tags: javascript, rendering, html5-canvas, pixel-manipulation

I am trying to draw an isometric square with some custom code to build the pixel data up and then put it on a canvas with putImageData.

But I'm not getting the expected results, after a quick look through the raw pixel data of the canvas it seems all the pixel data I built up is getting messed with.

What I want from the below code is a red diamond on a black background. Where am i going wrong?

```
var Drawing = {};

Drawing.DrawIsoMetricSquare = function(cRenderContext, x, y, iWidth, cColor) {
    var iHeight = iWidth / 2;

    var iYPos = Math.floor(iHeight / 2) + 1;
    var iXPos = 0;

    var iRenderGirth = 1;

    cPixelData = cRenderContext.createImageData(iWidth, iHeight);

    var bExpand = true;

    while (iXPos != iWidth) {
        var iCurrentRenderGirth = 0;

        while (iCurrentRenderGirth != iRenderGirth) {
            var iY = iYPos + iCurrentRenderGirth;
            //Draw first pixel then second
            Drawing.ColorPixelAtPos(cPixelData.data, iXPos, iY, iWidth, cColor);
            Drawing.ColorPixelAtPos(cPixelData.data, iXPos + 1, iY, iWidth, cColor);

            iCurrentRenderGirth++;
        }

        //Move to next Render Start
        iYPos = bExpand ? (iYPos - 1) : (iYPos + 1);
        iXPos += 2;
        iRenderGirth = bExpand ? (iRenderGirth + 2) : (iRenderGirth - 2);

        bExpand &= iRenderGirth < iHeight;
    }

    cRenderContext.putImageData(cPixelData, x, y);
};

Drawing.XYPosToPixelPos = function(x, y, iWidth) {
    return (x + y * iWidth) * 4;
};

Drawing.ColorPixelAtPos = function(cPixelData, x, y, iWidth, cColor) {
    var iPixPos = Drawing.XYPosToPixelPos(x, y, iWidth);

    cPixelData[iPixPos++] = cColor.r;
    cPixelData[iPixPos++] = cColor.g;
    cPixelData[iPixPos++] = cColor.b;
    cPixelData[iPixPos] = 1; //Fixed alpha for now
};

var eCanvas = $("<canvas></canvas>");
eCanvas[0].width = 50;
eCanvas[0].height = 50;

$("#render").append(eCanvas);

var cRenderContext = eCanvas[0].getContext('2d');
cRenderContext.fillStyle = "rgba(1, 1, 1, 1)";
cRenderContext.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

Drawing.DrawIsoMetricSquare(cRenderContext, 0, 0, 42, {
    r: 255,
    g: 0,
    b: 0
});
```

JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/reefbarman/E5NE3/2/)

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out your math problem, but in order to see red, you will want your fixed alpha to be 255, not 1.  I am getting a red v shape on the white background at least.

Comment: is that where im going wrong? I thought alpha was between 0 and 1? or is it different in the pixel data as compared to the css rgba?

Comment: I also imaging that its quite buggy and not producing the shaped I expected as I wasn't able to see anything to test it

Comment: I have fixed the maths it now renders a red diamond on a white rectangle on a black square. This question is a bit meaningless now but thanks for your help maybe if you want to answer it with why the alpha is different in the pixel data and that was my issue?

Comment: Yes, pixel data values are 4 bytes for r, g, b, and a.  Each value is a number between 0 and 255.  So for the alpha values in pixel data, 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully opaque.  I will look at the new fiddle with the corrected math I will help you get the red diamond on a black square and add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems were

- a math error which you already fixed.
- RGBA specifiers go from 0..255 not 0..1
- You need to fill your pixel data with black opaque pixels (they are white by default).

I added a few lines of code and made a new fiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/bsssq/1/

Now you should see the red diamond on the black square.